# FAcebook graph API - URL supplied invalid OAuthException: (#1500)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post a link via the php-dsk graph API. When I typed my URL at http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug , it was successful showing response code - 200.
But when I am trying to post a link to the facebook wall, the following error appears :-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid thrown     
in /home/a1395850/public_html/src/base_facebook.php on line 1254
```

I have the following in my scope :- 'email,publish_stream,publish_actions,user_likes'

The following is my code to post a link to the user's wall :-

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
 require 'src/facebook.php';
 include 'app_details.php';
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user) {
   try {
     $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
   } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     error_log($e);
     $user = null;
   }
 }



 $permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
 if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
// Permission is granted!
// Do the related task
 $args = array(
'message'   => 'Hello from app',
'link'      => 'laafo.uni.me',
'caption'   => 'Facebook API Tutorials!'
 );
 $post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);

 } else {
// We don't have the permission
// Alert the user or ask for the permission!
header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
 }


 ?>
```

Please help me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: `laafo.uni.me` is not an absolute URL, it is just a host name. Full URL would be something like `http://laafo.uni.me/`, so try that instead. (The debugger automatically adds the protocol `http://` as a browser would – but I don’t think the actual API is that forgiving.)

Comment: Tried http also, but the same error is being shown.

Answer (score 1):

The ability of posting into facebook wall using oauth authenticatoin has been removed from Feb 2013

Please search for '**Removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API**' in the below page.

[FB ROADMAP](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Vinoth . Can you please tell me that how can I post a link to the user's wall NOW?

Comment: I hope that is not possible.

Comment: No we can....You can se the demo at http://25labs.com/demo/fb/index.php They are posting links to the user's wall...

Comment: This website will NOT post anything to your wall or like any page automatically. See that link

Comment: That is "AUTOMATICALLY". But it will post if you ask it to do it. Click on the f-connect button and click "POST ABOUT 25LABS"

Comment: How you passed oauth token while posting?

Comment: sorry...I ticked again...It was by mistake...toggled it.

Comment: How you passed oauth token while posting?

Comment: hey please gothrough GRAPH API in facebook fully and come back Frd